# prove that : $\sum_{j=1}^{n} P(A_{j}) = E\{\sum_{j=1}^{n}(I_{A_{j}}-P(A_{j})) I_{\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_{i}}\}+\sum_{j=1}^{n} P(A_{j})(1-\beta) $

Tags: probability-theory

let $A_1, A_2, \dots,A_n$ be probability events.

Set :
$$\beta=1-P\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{n} A_{k}\right)$$

assume that $\beta > 0$ and prove that :

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n} P\left(A_{j}\right) = E\left\{\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(I_{A_{j}}-P\left(A_{j}\right)\right) I_{\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_{i}}\right\}+\sum_{j=1}^{n} P\left(A_{j}\right)(1-\beta) $$

where $I$ denotes the indicator function.

I feel like I need to use the property : $\sum_{j=1}^{n} P\left(A_{j}\right)=\sum_{j=1}^{n} P\left\{A_{j}, \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_{i}\right\}$ and then use some conditioning but I don't how to proceed, any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A = \cup_{i=1}^n A_i$ and note that $A_i \subset A$ for each $i = 1, ..., n$, so $I_{A_i} I_A = I_{A_i}$. Also, $1 - \beta = P(A)$. No conditioning needed.
\begin{align*}
&\quad E\left[\sum_{j=1}^n (I_{A_j} - P(A_j))I_A)\right] + \sum_{j=1}^n P(A_j)(1-\beta)\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n E[I_{A_j}I_A - P(A_j)I_A)] + P(A)\sum_{j=1}^n P(A_j)\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n [P(A_j) - P(A_j)P(A)] + P(A)\sum_{j=1}^n P(A_j)\\
&= (1-P(A)) \sum_{j=1}^nP(A_j) + P(A)\sum_{j=1}^n P(A_j) \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n P(A_j)
\end{align*}